# What is the C# equivalent of Delphi's TList?

Tags: c#, delphi

In Delphi I have a class and store instances of this class in a list, with this code:

```
type
    TMyClass = class
    public
        name: String;
        old: Integer;
        anx: boolean;
    end;
```

...

```
function x(aList: TList): String;
var
    aObj: TMyClass;
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i:= 1 to aList.Count do
    begin
        aObj := aList[i-1];
    end;
end;
```

How can I do this in C#?

How my class will receive a `TList`? And how do I write a `TList` equivalent in C#?

Comment: This is a "can I has teh codez" question, which is probably why you are getting down votes. The edits have hopefully improved it, but really, you have shown zero effort in asking the question, not even specifying anything you tried. (Did you even search in the  C# help? Did you even Google Lists in C#?)

Comment: @WarrenP I don't think so. The question is, "what class do I use in C# to hold lists of things"? That doesn't need code to answer. It is trivially easy to find the answer with a websearch though.

Comment: You probably saw it after my first round of edits. :-) I tried to de-canIHasTehCodez the question without changing it.

Comment: Regarding your [deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101156/how-i-can-convert-this-delphi-code-to-c), we will not port large chunks of code from one language to another. That's your job. You have to learn to do it yourself. We can help guide you, but we are not a free code writing service. If you continue to ask questions like that one, you will soon be banned from the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//this is the class with fields.
public class TMyClass
{
    public String Name;
    public int old;
    public bool anx;
}

//this is the class with properties.
public class TMyClass
{
    public String Name { get; set; };
    public int old { get; set; };
    public bool anx { get; set; };
}

public string x(List<TMyClass> list)
{
    TMyClass aObj;
    for(int i = 0; i++; i < list.Count)
    {
        aObj = list[i];
    }
    //NEED TO RETURN SOMETHING?
}
```

Here is a translation of your class and function. But I do believe your function needs to return something...

Answer (score 8):

The C# equivalent is the generic list container [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). It's very similar to Delphi's `TList` but is a typesafe container due to the use of generics. In fact in modern Delphi code, the generic Delphi class [`TList<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList) would be preferred over the non-generic `TList` because of type safety.

Assuming that you want a list of `MyClass` objects you would instantiate an instance of `List<MyClass>`.

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
```

and then you can add items

```
list.Add(obj);
```

and so on.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `TList<T>` exists in Delphi. (Of course, it doesn't exist until Delphi2009, so if the OP is using an ancient version like Delphi 7, then it doesn't apply.)